# How do i forbid a character in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

i would like to forbid "/" from a field.

I read in the doc that it should be something like that:

> valid_name_regex = /
>   validates :name, presence: true,
>                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }, format: { with: valid_name_regex }

But i'd like the opposite.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: true }, format: { with: /^[^\/]+$/ }
```

Comment: Regexp will fail on empty strings and add error to model's errors.

Comment: I'd use `%r{^[^/]*$}` for the regex. The alternate literal syntax makes escaping the slash unnecessary and `*` instead of `+` makes it work for empty strings.

Comment: how about this Regex pattern `/^[^\/'"]+$/`?  this would disallow backslash and empty strings

Comment: Thanks all of you, i used Gaurish' snippet